# Angular directive for affixing sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to affix the sidebar with respective to my main content. I have tried directive here. Though I succeed with top affix i.e it works and stick to top when scroll down, but it fails to scroll in-case my sidebar content is longer. I want to fix it to top and move it scrollable according to main content. but if its content it more then screen it should scroll to down as well and stick to bottom at same time.

```
<div class="background-white" sidebar-affix data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="80" data-offset-bottom="10">My sidebar content here</div>

.directive('sidebarAffix', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var originOffsetTop = element[0].offsetTop;
            scope.condition     = function() {
                return $window.pageYOffset > originOffsetTop;
            };

            angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    console.log($window.pageYOffset > originOffsetTop);
                    if (scope.condition()) {
                        angular.element(element).removeClass('affix-top');
                        angular.element(element).addClass('affix');
                    } else {
                        angular.element(element).addClass('affix-top');
                        angular.element(element).removeClass('affix');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

I want to be scrollable in case sidebar is longer than expected but it should stick to bottom in this case.

Comment: What are styles you are providing to .affix-top ? Is there any top  navigation bar exists ? If not try putting max-height: 100%  inside .affix-top.
Fiddle will help solving problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

What about giving your menu position:fixed; and top:XXpx then it will always will stay in the same place even if you scroll your content down

```css
.wrapper > div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.side-bar  {
  position:fixed;  
  top:10px;
}
.content {
  
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='side-bar'></div>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be old post. However, Did you consider having it a separate view and loading it in index page. Instead of handling it using css. By doing this you can write a separate controller to access only sidebar and of course it will be fixed and also you can add other view like header,footer and define a separate controller for each of them and define a separate container to load main content. This might not be an exact answer that you have asked for (directive). Just a suggestion.

Posting a sample html

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="SampleApp">
<head>
<body ng-controller="SampleController" >
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    <div data-ng-include="'header.html'" data-ng-controller="HeaderController" > </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
    <div class="page-container" id="container">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
        <div data-ng-include="sidebar.html'" data-ng-controller="SidebarController" > </div>
        <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div >
            <div class="page-content">
                <!-- BEGIN ACTUAL CONTENT -->
                <div ui-view class="fade-in-up"> </div>
                <!-- END ACTUAL CONTENT -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTAINER -->
    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <div data-ng-include="'footer.html'" data-ng-controller="FooterController" class="page-footer"> </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Set max-height to 100% and increase the margin-top to find the appropriate position to set the place 
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 50%;
adding max-height to body and margin top to div hope this fix the issue